# Why PHP is not scanning the directory specified by using 'PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR' environment variable?

Tags: php, windows, configuration, configuration-files, php-ini

I'm using **PHP 7.2.11** on my laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System**.

I've installed **PHP 7.2.11** and **Apache/2.4.35 (Win32)** using the latest version of **XAMPP for Windows**.

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` is at location `C:/xampp/htdocs`

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = C:/xampp/htdocs
```

Please check the steps I followed :

1. I created a folder titled **php_playground** inside the folder(i.e. inside the **DOCUMENT_ROOT**)
2. Inside the folder **php_playground** I created a file titled **.htaccess (C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground.htaccess)**
3. Inside the folder **php_playground** I created a folder titled **Test (C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\Test)**
4. Inside the folder **Test** I created an empty file titled **test.ini (C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\Test\test.ini)**
5. Inside the file **.htaccess** I wrote below code :

   SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\Test\
6. Inside the folder **php_playground** I created a file titled **demo.php**

Inside the file **demo.php** I've written below code :

```
<?php

  //var_dump(getenv('PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR')); string(36) "C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\Test\" 

  var_dump(php_ini_scanned_files());

?>
```

The output of above code in my web browser is :

```
bool(false)
```

Why PHP is not giving me the expected output in the form of complete path to the file **test.ini** and not scanning that file?

Comment: Can you show us the PHP code that you are running

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Please check the updated question body. I've added the code that I'm executing and seeing the output of it in my web browser.

Comment: Why aren't you setting this in your system environment variables? `.htaccess` files are read when the directory is accessed. Even if it were in the main Apache config, who knows if it will process the `SetEnv` directive before it loads the PHP SAPI.

Comment: @miken32 : How should I set this in my system environment variables? I don't have an idea about it. Please explain.